How to get a MongoDB query to use indexes in a join?
I am trying to learn how to use MongoDB and have two collections that I am trying to join and find records with search criteria in each.  In the main collection I have an index on the text field (allergies) being searched by regex and that index is being used; however, the joined collection has an index on the field (device_brand) being searched and that index is not being used.  When I execute a simple find query within the single collection (device_data) for the device_brand, the index is being used.  How do I get the join to use both the respective indexes?
db.medical_records.aggregate([{$lookup:
  {
        from: "device_data",
        localField: "patient_id",
        foreignField: "patient_id",
        as: "same"
    }
   },
   {
      $match: { $and: [ {"allergies" :{$regex :/cat/}}, {"same.device_brand": "APPLE"} ] }
   }
])

The json for each are:
medical_records:
  patient_id: 000001,
  name: 'Steven Jones',
  date_of_birth: '1944-11-25',
  gender: 'M',
  medical_conditions: 'heart arrhythmia, high blood pressure',
  medications: 'digoxin, atorvastatin',
  allergies: 'cat dander, shellfish'

device_data:
    _id: ObjectId('6744d8810afc348db9457127'),
    patient_id: 000001,
    name: 'Steven Jones',
    date_of_birth: '1944-11-25',
    device_brand: 'APPLE',
    device_model: 'SE',
    device_type: 'SmartWatch',
    heart_rate_min: 90,
    heart_rate_median: 97.2,
    heart_rate_max: 105,
    resting_heart_rate: 90,
    heart_rate_variability: '50ms'

I tried search the web and reading the MongoDB documentation but it does not seem to cover this.  I got the hint for a join query from stackoverflow and the results come back correctly; just not very quickly because it is not using the index and there are 100,000 documents in each collection.

try hint https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/meta/hint/

"I tried search the web and reading the MongoDB documentation but it does not seem to cover this." - there's plenty of docs on this. Read: Regex Index Use,  Lookup Performance Considerations. For further optimisation, do the allergy match before the lookup since it's in the source collection. And use $match on device_brand in the lookup pipeline instead of after.

What makes you think it's not using the index? And do you really want it using an index on device_brand rather than patient_id (or a compound index with both)?

You are using MongoDB as a relational database.  You are missing the best parts of a document-based database (i.e., co-located data on the same record).

@user20042973, In mongodb;s compass console it will show you how many times an index is used verifyuing that it was not using the index.

@barrypicker, the device_data was not designed to be an embedded document because it would exceed the 16 MB limit.
